# File's size and string's size difference, why is that?

Tags: c#

I found there is a strange size difference between the size of the string and the size of the file, why is that and how to resolve this issue?

This is how I get the string's size:

```
int bytesInStr = Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(str);
```

Initially I want to create a file of some size. So in my loop I calculate the total size of all the written strings:

```
totalSize+=bytesInStr
```

But the file's size is around twice less.

Comment: You should create an [mcve], why is this an issue also?..Why does the file size matter?

Comment: The size of a text file is the number of bytes used to represent the text in the encoding chosen for that file. `Unicode` is 16-bit for every character.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Is the byte order mark (BOM) taken into account?

Comment: Just resolved the issue by replacing Unicode with ASCII

Comment: For the file size, if the file contains a BOM, then yes, obviously.

Comment: By switching to ASCII you're saying that the encoding chosen for the file is 1-byte-per-character. If that is not true then you have an error waiting to happen. For instance, if the file encoding is UTF8 then *most* normal characters are 1-byte-per-character, but some are 2 or 3.

Answer (score 2):

Your file is written with a different encoding than the one you're using to get the byte count of the string. You need to use the same (e.g. `Encoding.Unicode`) for both.

Answer (score 1):

What Luaan said is completely right, but even if you match the encodings, there will be a slight difference. First because of the file summary and attributes which are not read in the stream, second, it might be because of the file system, either causing fragmentation or compression. It's obvious if you open the properties window of your file, size on disk and the original size differ. Why? Well that needs more than my knowledge.
Hope it helped.